# Boost lexical_cast<std::string>(int) MSVC 2008 bug

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I wanted to try out Apache Thrift using VC++2008 and ran into unforseen problems. In a Debug Build i get the error `"string iterators incompatible"` inside the VC++ runtime library. I tracked it down to a call to `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(int)` and was able to trigger the bug in a simple test program.

The following fails with the mentioned iterator error (this is with boost 1.55):

```
std::string test = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(5);
```

Everything works fine in a Release build with the correct behaviour. And for some reason this line only fails in the thrift code and works in a minimal test program.

I already tried setting `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` to 0 but that has no effect since the debug runtime library is compiled with this flag set. I tried selecting the release multithreaded runtime dll even in debug build but that did not result in the release dll beeing used. This is even a bad idea since I use other boost compiled libraries that link to the debug runtime dll.

I've run out of ideas, what could I try to resolve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because the debug build used the thrift release mode library.